# How do I add an image and a text to a gameobject?

Tags: unity

I did the following:

I added a canvas to main camera.
I added a UI image to the canvas and named it "BackgroundImage" and made its color red and set its fill mode to "stretch / stretch".
I added another UI image to the canvas, name it "ButtonBackground" and selected "Source Image" "Builtin/extras/InputFieldBackground"

I add a script named "VirtualKeyboard" to the canvas. This script has a property named "ButtonBack". I drag the sprite "ButtonBackground" into this slot.

Next, I run my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VirtualKeyboard : MonoBehaviour
{
      public Sprite ButtonBack;

    void Start()
    {
        Canvas canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();

        string sName = "name1";

        GameObject key = new GameObject(sName);

        RectTransform keyRectTransform = key.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        keyRectTransform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
        keyRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(100,100);
        keyRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 200);

        // Add Image component to the key
        Image image = key.GetComponent<Image>();
        if (image == null)
        {
            image = key.AddComponent<Image>();
        }
        image.sprite = ButtonBack;
        image.type = Image.Type.Sliced;

        // Add a Text component to the key and set its text to the current key string
        Text text = key.GetComponent<Text>();
        if (text == null)
        {
            text = key.AddComponent<Text>();
        }
        text.text = "test";
    }
}
```

"text" is null. Why is that?

The console says:
Can't add 'Text' to name1 because a 'Image' is already added to the game object!
A GameObject can only contain one 'Graphic' component.
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ()
VirtualKeyboard:Start () (at Assets/VirtualKeyboard.cs:37)

However, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: This code looks very strange: `Text text = key.GetComponent<Text>(); if (text == null)...`. There's no code before this line that could *possibly* cause `key` to have a `Text` component attached to it, since it was just created as an empty game object with no components other than a `Transform`.

Comment: I wanted to be perfectly sure...

Comment: You can be perfectly sure that a newly-constructed `GameObject` has only a `Transform` component until you add something else to it. I also note that you're importing the Text Mesh Pro namespace (`using TMPro`), but then using legacy UI text instead of `TextMeshProUGUI` — any reason for that?

Comment: @DMGregory I wanted to use TMPro, but then I was afraid that I might not be able to use it correctly and went for a Text instead to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong.

Each game object can only contain one `Graphic` component. Both `Image` and `Text` inherit from `Graphic` - so only one can be drawn by a single game object.

In the Unity editor, create a new UI button using the GameObject menu (GameObject -> Create -> UI -> Button). You'll see exactly how they solve this: the button object hosts the `Image` component, and it has *a child object* that hosts the `Text` component.